# Average distance within group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, euclidean-distance

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A','A','B','B','B'],
    'x': [1,1,2,2,3],
    'y': [1,2,2,3,3]
})
```

[image]

The output I want is the average distance for each point in the group, in this example

group A: `(distance((1,1),(1,2))) /1 = 1`

group B: `(distance((2,2),(2,3)) + distance((2,3),(3,3)) + distance((2,2),(3,3))) /3 = 1.138`

[image]

I can calculate the distance using `np.linalg.norm` but I confused to use it in pandas `groupby`. Thank you

Note: 1 of my idea is I am trying to make this dataframe first (where I stuck), which is contains the pairs of point that I need to calculate the distance and after this I just need to calculate distance and groupby mean

[image]

Comment: `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: spatial.distance.pdist(np.array(list(zip(x.x, x.y)))).mean())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `numpy broadcasting`:

```
def calc_avg_distance(group):
    x = group[['x', 'y']].values
    dist_matrix = np.sqrt(((x - x[:, np.newaxis])**2).sum(axis=2))
    np.fill_diagonal(dist_matrix, np.nan)
    avg_distance = np.nanmean(dist_matrix)
    return avg_distance


(df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: calc_avg_distance(x))
 .reset_index(name='avg_distance'))
```

Output:

```
 id  avg_distance
0  A      1.000000
1  B      1.138071
```

Comment: thank you it is working but actually it is a little bit difficult to me to understand this part `(x - x[:, np.newaxis])`

Comment: That corresponds to the numpy broadcasting. I would suggest to learn it, as broadcasting solutions tend to be quite fast. You can learn it at: [Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), @d_frEak.

Comment: I found out that it will return warning if all the element of dist_matrix are nan (only 1 point), so I modified the avg_distance calculation like this `avg_distance = np.NaN if np.all(dist_matrix!=dist_matrix) else np.nanmean(dist_matrix)`